# Having some issues Queuing MQTT serialized messages

Tags: python, c#, mqtt

I am having some issues queueing some data from a pythons script into c# application. At a high level, I have a python script with some hard coded values being serialized and sent it over MQTT. C# application is subscribing to these messages.

On C# end, I subscribe to a topic, that will receive this messages, and print out some ID value every time a message is received.

So far, values has not been consistent, meaning 20 messages are sent from python but on the C# side, not all of them are received.

Output example:

```
0
Try deserialize protobuf message
System.IO.MemoryStream
1
Try deserialize protobuf message
System.IO.MemoryStream
2
Try deserialize protobuf message
System.IO.MemoryStream
3
Try deserialize protobuf message
System.IO.MemoryStream
5
Try deserialize protobuf message
System.IO.MemoryStream
7
Try deserialize protobuf message
System.IO.MemoryStream
8
Try deserialize protobuf message
System.IO.MemoryStream
9
Try deserialize protobuf message
System.IO.MemoryStream
10
Try deserialize protobuf message
System.IO.MemoryStream
12
Try deserialize protobuf message
System.IO.MemoryStream
13
Try deserialize protobuf message
System.IO.MemoryStream
14
Try deserialize protobuf message
System.IO.MemoryStream
15
Try deserialize protobuf message
System.IO.MemoryStream
18
Try deserialize protobuf message
System.IO.MemoryStream
19
```

From the output above: 6, 11, 16, 17 never made it through.

Python Code:

```py
import paho.mqtt.client as paho import AIML_pb2 import datetime as dt import time

def on_publish(client,userdata,result):                         #create function for callback
    print("data published \n")
    pass

def mqtt(buf):
    broker="127.0.0.1"
    port=1883

    client1= paho.Client("control1")                                #create client object
    client1.on_publish = on_publish                                 #assign function to callback
   
    client1.connect(broker,port)                                    #establish connection
    try:
        ret= client1.publish("/SERVICES/RESPONSE/ECG/UDCMGR/AIML",buf)  #publish
    except:
        print("Waiting to publish!")
    

def main():

    detections = AIML_pb2.ObjectDetectionParametersBroadcast()

    for i in range(0, 20):
        detections.timestamp = dt.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')
        detections.frameID = i
        detections.objectType = "cell phone"
        detections.conf = 0.90
        detections.top_x = 0.5
        detections.top_y = 0.6
        detections.bottom_x = 0.7
        detections.bottom_y = 0.9
        buf = detections.SerializeToString()
        mqtt(buf)
        print (i)
        time.sleep(1)
main()
```

C# Code:

```cs
if (e.Topic == "/SERVICES/RESPONSE/ECG/UDCMGR/AIML")
{
    Queue <byte[]> objectDetected = new Queue<byte[]>();
                    
    objectDetected.Enqueue(e.Message);

    foreach (var id in objectDetected)
    {
     Console.WriteLine(id);
     ScriptAPIs.aimlStatus = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't appear to be specifying any [QOS](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc398718099) level (set on [publish](https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt/#publish) and subscribe). This means QOS0; "At most once delivery" (so no guarantee of delivery). If not loosing messages is important to you then use QOS1 or 2. At QOS0 you should expect to lose some messages (this would generally be pretty rare when running over a LAN with a second delay between messages but there is not enough info, e.g. broker configuration and logs, to comment further)

Comment: In addition to the above the issue may be with your encoding. Try logging `e.Message` and confirm every message received is being correctly decoded.

Comment: You are also creating a new client for every message and reusing the same client id. You should only be creating one client and reusing it (and starting the client loop)